# Integrate a floating action button into linear layout with toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I have the following RecyclerView to which I want to I add a floating action button. but the problem is the floating action button is separate from the RecyclerView part (it's divide the screen to two parts).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayoutandroid:id="@+id/swifeRefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/material_design_android_floating_action_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="244dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
    fab:menu_fab_label="Floating Action Menu"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_24dp"
        fab:fab_label="Menu Item 1"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_24dp"
        fab:fab_label="Menu Item 2"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_24dp"
        fab:fab_label="Menu Item 3"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I would love if someone can help me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another `RelativeLayout` below `ToolBar` and place both `RecyclerView` & `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu` inside `RelativeLayout`.

Also change your `RecyclerView` as below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Here is the complete working code. Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swifeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
                android:id="@+id/material_design_android_floating_action_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="244dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
                fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
                fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
                fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
                fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
                fab:menu_fab_label="Floating Action Menu"
                fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
                fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
                fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
                fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
                fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
                fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
                fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
                fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
                fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
                fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
                fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
                fab:menu_labels_position="left"
                fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
                fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
                fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
                fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
                fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
                fab:menu_openDirection="up"
                fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
                fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
                fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
                fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
                fab:menu_showShadow="true">

                <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_refresh"
                    fab:fab_label="Menu Item 1"
                    fab:fab_size="mini" />

                <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_refresh"
                    fab:fab_label="Menu Item 2"
                    fab:fab_size="mini" />

                <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_refresh"
                    fab:fab_label="Menu Item 3"
                    fab:fab_size="mini" />
            </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: @asaproG Glad to know that :)

Comment: @asaproG If my answer seems useful please give an up vote. Thanks in advance :)